# Get details of contact in single query

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

Hi all I am trying to get contact information from the contact database using ContentResolver with these field  want to get name, number, FORMATTED_ADDRESS, PHOTO
details for a contact in one single query.

So basically I need to make 3 queries per contact to obtain these 
details.

What I want to know is that, is there a simpler and more efficient way 
to achieve what this.

but using the below code i am getting exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1
```

Can any body help me for finding the solution for the same.

```
Uri uri                = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection    = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO};
String selection       = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '1'";
String[] selectionArgs = null;
String sortOrder       = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

Cursor contacts          = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe problem will be at `selection`. Replace yours method with mine.

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO};
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER  + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(1) }; 
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

You should always use `parametrized statements`. Your approach is dangerous. And your URI was bad.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am getting the same Exception after implementing your code `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1`

Comment: try it now, you had bad uri. I have not noticed it immediately.

Comment: after removing selection and selectionArgs from the query it works for me but it wont give me the FORMATTED_ADDRESS in place of this it it gives PHONE_NUMBER dont know why. But on debugging i found the columns it returns Are "_id, display_name, data1, data1, data15" it wont give the original name for them. One more problem it gives cursor with less no. of records, and i have many more records in the contact book

Comment: yes now i am trying with this URI ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI

Comment: so for get FORMATTED_ADRESS you need to use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI`

Comment: yes I know that, but for getting only FORMATTED_ADDRESS I have to make query again after first query for contactID for this and if records are 250 or more it takes around 30-40 second for all records And the same re-query i have to make for PHOTo and other data.

Comment: i know but in one query it not possible it seems because you need data from two different URIs.

Comment: Yes, actually i want a single cursor with all the field, i am showing these field in the `ListView` for this i have used `CursorAdapter` and also using `Filterable` for filtering values text entered in the `EditText` and i am filtering list on the basis of  `FORMATTED_ADDRESS` and for `FORMATTED_ADDRESS` there will be different `cursor` which `CursorAdapter` won't support

Comment: is this line correct?? String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER " + " = ?";

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

Replace

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
```

with

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
```

Comment: thanks Vipul for your reply, i have used your given URI and after removing selection and selectionArgs from the query it works for me but it wont give me the FORMATTED_ADDRESS in place of this it it gives PHONE_NUMBER dont know why. But on debugging i found the columns it returns Are "_id, display_name, data1, data1, data15" it wont give the original name for them. One more problem it gives cursor with less no. of records, and i have many more records in the contact book

Comment: try executing Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null,null,null);

Comment: what would be the URI? ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

Comment: ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

Comment: around 72 columns it returned but non will give FORMATTED_ADDRESS  and PHOTO